# Align top-margin for icons in description list

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, description, fontawesome, icon

**Problem:**

I have a problem aligning icons in a `description` so they match the top of the correspondent text to the right of them.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[medfamily,textosf,mathlf,mnsy,amsbb,mixedgreek,minionint,openg,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[onlytext,medfamily,osf]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\introicons}
\setlength{\introicons}{\widthof{\faEnvelopeO}}
\addtolength{\introicons}{\labelsep}
\SetLabelAlign{CenterWithParen}{\makebox[\introicons]{#1}}

\begin{description}[
      itemsep=0.75em, 
      topsep=0pt, 
      parsep=0pt, 
      partopsep=0pt, 
      labelwidth=\introicons, 
      itemindent=0cm, 
      leftmargin=!, 
      rightmargin=0cm, 
      align=CenterWithParen
  ]
  \item[\centering \large \faHtml5] \blindtext[1]
  \item[\centering \faEnvelopeO] \blindtext[1]
  \item[\centering \large \faMobilePhone] \blindtext[1]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

**Visual example:**

[image]

Notice how the HTML5 and cell phone icon are not aligned to the top of the text while the e-mail icon is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I use `scalerel` to make the icons the vertical footprint of a capital `X`. (I also removed `\centering` from the icon calls, as it seemed superfluous).  Note that, because `scalerel` processes arguments in math mode by default, the use of `$` delimiters actually forces the evaluation of the icons in text mode. Instaces of `\large` were also removed, as `scalerel` doesn't need them to scale to the specified size.

**REVISED SOLUTION** (Fixed width, variable height, but top-aligned icons)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
%\usepackage[medfamily,textosf,mathlf,mnsy,amsbb,mixedgreek,minionint,openg,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
%\usepackage[onlytext,medfamily,osf]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scalerel,graphicx,stackengine}
\def\mydim{15pt}
\newcommand\scalewd[2][\mydim]{%
\fboxsep=\fboxrule%
  \setbox0=\hbox{X}%
  \smash{\belowbaseline[-\ht0]{%
    \rotatebox[origin=right]{-90}{%
      \scaleto{\rotatebox[origin=right]{90}{\belowbaseline[0pt]{#2}}}{#1}%
    }%
  }}%
}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\introicons}
\setlength{\introicons}{\widthof{\faEnvelopeO}}
\addtolength{\introicons}{\labelsep}
\SetLabelAlign{CenterWithParen}{\makebox[\introicons]{#1}}
\begin{description}[
      itemsep=0.75em, 
      topsep=0pt, 
      parsep=0pt, 
      partopsep=0pt, 
      labelwidth=\introicons, 
      itemindent=0cm, 
      leftmargin=!, 
      rightmargin=0cm, 
      align=CenterWithParen
  ]
  \item[\scalewd{\faHtml5}] \blindtext[1]
  \item[\scalewd{\faEnvelopeO}] \blindtext[1]
  \item[\scalewd{\faMobilePhone}] \blindtext[1]
\end{description}

\clearpage\def\mydim{20pt}
\begin{description}[
      itemsep=0.75em, 
      topsep=0pt, 
      parsep=0pt, 
      partopsep=0pt, 
      labelwidth=\introicons, 
      itemindent=0cm, 
      leftmargin=!, 
      rightmargin=0cm, 
      align=CenterWithParen
  ]
  \item[\scalewd{\faHtml5}] \blindtext[1]
  \item[\scalewd{\faEnvelopeO}] \blindtext[1]
  \item[\scalewd{\faMobilePhone}] \blindtext[1]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

15pt default icon width

[image]

20 pt icon width

[image]

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION** (Fixed height, variable width icons)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
%\usepackage[medfamily,textosf,mathlf,mnsy,amsbb,mixedgreek,minionint,openg,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
%\usepackage[onlytext,medfamily,osf]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\introicons}
\setlength{\introicons}{\widthof{\faEnvelopeO}}
\addtolength{\introicons}{\labelsep}
\SetLabelAlign{CenterWithParen}{\makebox[\introicons]{#1}}

\begin{description}[
      itemsep=0.75em, 
      topsep=0pt, 
      parsep=0pt, 
      partopsep=0pt, 
      labelwidth=\introicons, 
      itemindent=0cm, 
      leftmargin=!, 
      rightmargin=0cm, 
      align=CenterWithParen
  ]
  \item[\scalerel*{$\faHtml5$}{X}] \blindtext[1]
  \item[\scalerel*{$\faEnvelopeO$}{X}] \blindtext[1]
  \item[\scalerel*{$\faMobilePhone$}{X}] \blindtext[1]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a great solution, with the exception that I would like to scale the icons up. What would I need to add to your code to achieve this?

Comment: @kexxcream what do you mean "scale them up"?  Relative to what?  For example, you could `\scalerel*{$\faHtml5$}{\rule{0pt}{10pt}}`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I would like the icons to be the same width as the icon that is the widest.

Comment: @kexxcream So you want the icons of fixed width, but varying height?

Comment: That is correct. While they will have varying height, they should all be centered relative to each other and also to the top as they currently are.

Comment: @kexxcream Please see my revisions

Comment: This is pure magic. Much appreciated, you just contributed to making a future book even more elegant and for that I'm grateful.